# Java Binary Tree entered in a specific order

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am trying to complete an assignment where I need to write a Java program to take a string from the command line, and implement it as a Binary Tree in a specific order, then get the depth of the binary tree.

For example: "((3(4))7((5)9))"

would be entered as a tree with 7 as the root, 3 and 9 as the children, and 4 as a right child of 3, and 5 as a left child of 9.

My code is below.. The problem I am having is that, because I am basing my checks off of finding a right bracket, I am unsure how to get the elements correctly when they are not directly preceding the brackets, such as the 3 in the above string. Any direction would be greatly appreciated..

```
class Node {
      int value;
      Node left, right;
    }

class BST {

public Node root;

// Add Node to Tree
public void add(int n) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node( );
        root.value = n;
    }
    else {
        Node marker = root;
        while (true) {
            if (n < marker.value) {
                if (marker.left == null) {
                    marker.left = new Node( );
                    marker.left.value = n;
                    break;
                } else {
                    marker = marker.left;
                }
            } else {
                if (marker.right == null) {
                    marker.right = new Node( );
                    marker.right.value = n;
                    break;
                } else {
                    marker = marker.right;
                }
            }
        }
    }
} // End ADD

//Find Height of Tree
public int height(Node t) {
    if (t.left == null && t.right == null) return 0;
    if (t.left == null) return 1 + height(t.right);
    if (t.right == null) return 1 + height(t.left);
    return 1 + Math.max(height(t.left), height(t.right));
} // End HEIGHT

// Check if string contains an integer
public static boolean isInt(String s) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
        return true;
} // End ISINT

public int elementCount(String[] a) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (isInt(a[i])) count++;
    }
    return count;
}

} // End BST Class

public class Depth {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = args[0].split(" ");
    BST tree = new BST();
    int[] bcount = new int[10];
    int[] elements = new int[10];
    int x = 0, bracketcount = 0;

    // Display entered string
    System.out.print("Entered Format: ");
    for (int j=0; j < a.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(a[j]);
    }

    for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
        char c = a[i].charAt(0);
        switch (c)
        {
            case '(':
                bracketcount++;
                break;
            case ')':
                if (isInt(a[i-1])) {
                    bcount[x] = bracketcount--;
                    elements[x++] = Integer.parseInt(a[i-1]);
                }
                break;
            case '1':
            case '7': 
            default : // Illegal character
                if ( (a[i-1].charAt(0) == ')') && (a[i+1].charAt(0) == '(') ) {
                    bcount[x] = bracketcount;
                    elements[x++] = Integer.parseInt(a[i]);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nTotal elements: " + tree.elementCount(a));
    // Display BracketCounts
    for (int w = 0; w < x; w++) {
        System.out.print(bcount[w] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    // Display Elements Array
    for (int w = 0; w < x; w++) {
        System.out.print(elements[w] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("\nDepth: " + tree.height(tree.root));


    // Build the tree
    for (int y = 0; y < x-1; y++) {
        for (int z = 1; z < tree.height(tree.root); z++) {
            if (bcount[y] == z) {
                tree.add(elements[y]);
            }
        }
    }
}  // End Main Function

public static boolean isInt(String s) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
        return true;
}

} // End Depth Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a couple of statements to get access to a tree with that kind of shape:

For input string : input=  "((3(4))7((5)9))"

You could do :

```
public class Trial {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String input =  "((3(4))7((5)9))";

        String easier = input.replaceAll("\\(\\(", "");
        String evenEasier = easier.replaceAll("\\)\\)", "");
        System.out.println(evenEasier);

        int firstVal = Integer.parseInt(evenEasier.substring(0, 1));


        int firstBracketVal = Integer.parseInt(evenEasier.substring(2, 3));

        int middleVal = Integer.parseInt(evenEasier.substring(3, 4));

        int secondBracketVal = Integer.parseInt(evenEasier.substring(4,5));

        int lastVal = Integer.parseInt(evenEasier.substring(6));

        System.out.println("First Val:"+firstVal);
        System.out.println("First bracket Val:"+firstBracketVal);
        System.out.println("Middle Val:"+middleVal);
        System.out.println("Second Bracket Val:"+secondBracketVal);
        System.out.println("Last Val:"+lastVal);

    }

}
```

This however would only ever work for entries in that specific format, if that were to change, or the length of the input goes up - this would work a bit or break.....If you need to be able to handle more complicated trees as input in this format a bit more thought would be needed on how to best handle and convert into your internal format for processing.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this string was only one example, I am unsure what will be used to test it, so the program needs to be able to handle different strings of varying length and children-nodes.

Comment: Right I see, well I hope it helped to some point...I am a litte unsure of what you were looking for here. Up voting a useful answer would be useful for others who are trying to help.

Comment: I would love to. It tells me I need 15 reputation to upvote anything, however.

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode:

```
function getNode(Node)
    get one char;
    if (the char is "(")
        getNode(Node.left);
        get one char;
    end if;

    Node.value = Integer(the char);

    get one char;
    if (the char is "(")
        getNode(Node.right);
        get one char;
    end if;
    //Now the char is ")" and useless.
end function
```

Before calling this function, you should get a "(" first.

---

In this method, the framwork of a Node in string is "[leftchild or NULL] value [rightchild or NULL])".
"("is not belong to the Node, but ")" is.